# xpath - grab content only if preceding div has certain word

Tags: xpath

I want to grab the textual content of this span class but only on the condition the word 'Country' is used in the code before it:

```
<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="/testurl.html"
itemprop="url" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Breadcrumbs', 'click', 'Country', 2, this.href); ">
<span itemprop="title">China</span></a><img src="http://imagepath.gif" class="fake class" 
alt="">
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

To be clear, if the xpath query sees the word 'Country' I want it to return the word 'China'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking previous element, try to check parent element. Because, in the sample markup, the span is located within the element that contains word `'Country'` :

```
//span[parent::a[contains(@onclick,'Country')]]
```

Above XPath search for `<span>` element that has parent `<a>` element with attribute `onclick` value contains `'Country'`.